# How can I force remember me for a realm in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to keep user as long as possible in my keycloak realm.

I increased the `SSO Session Max` value and it works as long as user has not closed the browser.

But if the user closes the browser and reopens it then it again redirects me to the login page.

How can I force the **remember me** functionality for an entire realm?

I want my session to not be invalidated when I close browser.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to your question in the end?